# Is this the right way of finding the Pearson coefficient?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I want to see the effect of discounts on sales. The discount is always 100 off and occurs in select months. I want to see what effect the 100 discount has on sales. I found the Pearson coefficient to be ~0.8 using the `correl` function in Excel.

My first array is the number of units sold every month. My comparison array is discount - everything on this column is 0 or 100.

Would this be the right approach? I'm not familiar with this type of work and the fact that the discount is constant is really throwing me off.

With a Pearson coefficient of ~0.8, does this mean that ~80% of purchases is made because of the discount?

Edit: 100 discount as in 100 dollars, didn't include the sign because it messed with formatting... sorry about that.

I know this entire set up seems a little illogical, but can someone point me on the right decision?

Comment: The question seems ill-posed. I take your word that MS Excel has a function called `correl()` that calculates Pearson correlation. But the real issue seems to be is this the right quantity to calculate to summarize the effect of a discount. The answer will be No, regardless, but saying what you should do instead is much more problematic. For a start, what your data are precisely is not clear to me. For a second, how can you disentangle the effect of a discount from other influences on sales? I think you need to be much more detailed about your set-up and assumptions.

Comment: As an aside, doesn't a 100% discount mean the thing is free?

Comment: @NickCox I am sure there are other influences to sales, but right now I only want to look at discount. The hypothesis is that customers will wait for the sale to come on to make a purchase of this product. I want to test this hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlation coefficient is a measure of association between two variables. The Pearson correlation coefficient that Excel uses with `correl` looks at 2 continuous variables, and assumes they are normally distributed. You have one continuous and one dichotomous (or binary) variable - there was a discount or there wasn't. You could use a point-biserial correlation (not sure if Excel does that), which correlates a continuous variable and a binary variable, but you probably should do instead a simple t-test, which Excel does with `t.test`. That will compare the mean sales for times with the discount vs times without, and assess the statistical significance. This also assumes normality in your sales variable, so you should check that. If it isn't normal you can do some transformations - if it is skewed you could do a logarithmic transformation which often normalizes a skewed variable, and is easily interpretable as proportional increase in sales, rather than raw increase.

For your question on does *r*=.80 mean 80% of sales is associated with the discount, that's not *r*, but $r^2$ that you want. Simply take the correlation coefficient and square it, and that is how you interpret the percent of variability associated with the discount (we say "explained" but that's not correct if you think of explained to mean caused). But again, I don't think you want a correlation, but a test of means.

There's one other, really important point that Nick brought up that you need to recognize: your assumption about causality is not appropriate. You should not be talking about "how much sales is due to or caused by the discount." That takes experimental or near experimental conditions, or really strong time-series modeling. With just 2 variables, all you can talk about is association. It is up to you or the decision-maker to decide if you think that has causal implications, but the statistics clearly do not support that. If you come to the conclusion it is based on your beliefs about the situation - that is not a bad thing to do (in fact, most of us in our daily life do it all the time), but do not say that the numbers tell you that.